# Ajax - JQuery, Array to query string

Tags: javascript, arrays, jquery

I am trying to use JQuery to send a JavaScript Array object over Ajax. Everything i have read points to using a JSON array, can it not be done with a standard Array?

Example:

```
   var data = new Array;
   data['type']  = 'author_list';
   data['limit'] = 10;

   $.ajax(
   {
      url      : '/transporter.php/',
      dataType : 'json',
      data     :  data,
      type     :  'GET',
      success  : function(json) 
      {
         console.log(json);
      }
   });
```

This method is what i use when working with DOJO. I am hoping its the same with JQuery..

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use an object and not an array:

```
  var data = {};
   data['type']  = 'author_list';
   data['limit'] = 10;

   $.ajax(
   {
      url      : '/transporter.php/',
      dataType : 'json',
      data     :  data,
      type     :  'GET',
      success  : function(json) 
      {
         console.log(json);
      }
   });
```

Also, JSON is what will be returned by the page you are requesting, not what you are sending to that page.  JSON is a string representation of an object, you are passing an actual object to the `ajax` method.